# How can I create a dynamic function that pulls data from mysql database and builds a form in Symfony 4?

Tags: database, forms, symfony, entity, formbuilder

I want to build a Controller that will load data from the database and built a form from it, but depending on the slug.

```
public function form($slug, Request $request){
   $EntityName = 'App\\Entity\\' . ucwords($slug);
   $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->find($id);
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
```

So this means, if the slug is for example `products` then I want to build a form from my database table `products with all the fields that are inside this table:

So in `products` I have for example the fields `id, name, color`. So the output I would need is

```
  ->add('id', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
  ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
  ->add('color', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
```

But if my slug is for example `members` and in my `members` table the fields are `id, username, email` then a form with this fields should be builded:

```
 ->add('id', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
  ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
  ->add('email', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
```

The problem for me is now how to create this fields that are depending on the slug. I was thinking to somehow get the fields from the object `$item`. This is the object `$item`:

```
 object(App\Entity\Members)#4788 (6) {
      ["id":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
      int(9)
      ["username":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
      string(13) "123"
      ["plainPassword":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
      NULL
      ["password":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
      string(7) "1@12.sw"
      ["isActive":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
      bool(true)
    }
```

I was trying to work with `get_object_vars` but this is not working with private objects, so I guess this is not a good solution. I also tried to create an array `($array =  (array) $item;)` from the object to build the form stucture with foreach. But it does not seem to be the right way neither.

Do you have any experience with functions that are loading data dynamically from database tables and create a form? I am happy for every idea or advice.

Comment: What do you want to do this ? Just asking because there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: if all your entities are Doctrine Entities you could easily use ClassMetaData which contains all information which you require per entity, see documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.html): e.g. use `$class = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('Entities\User');`

Comment: Why do you want to define all your entity properties as a form input? What is the purpose of this need? It's a strange case

Comment: @LBA this is maybe what I am looking for... Could you give an example?

Comment: @FabienPapet I have for example 100 different tables. For the content of each table I want to have a form with all the data, so that I can edit it. If I do not find a dynamic function for it, then I have to write every form manually. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Mcsky Because I want to make them editable

Comment: Then I think @LBA 's solution is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
$cmf = $em->getMetadataFactory();
$class = $cmf->getMetadataFor($entityName);

foreach ($class->fieldMappings as $fieldMapping) {
  echo $fieldMapping['fieldName'] . "\n";
}
```

This will give you all fields for your Entity based on Doctrine's Metadata model.

Check out [ClassMetadata API documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadata.html) for more information and especially which information you'll get there.

E.g. you could use something like

- `isNullable(string $fieldName)` to ensure some 'mandatory validation'
- `getIdentifierColumnNames()` to exclude all identifier columns (note: this will return column names not entity fields, but you can easily identify these
- `getTypeOfField` to get some hint whether a field is a string or a number (again to allow more specific form attributes)
- etc... just check the documentation and try it

BUT generally be careful using the ClassMetadata as your use case is not really what it's meant for - but we use it for a similar case as well.

Comment: I just tested your code, but I do not get any output

Comment: be sure to use the right $entityName and that $em is set to your EntityManager - won't be able to look into your code. this is working.

Comment: I added `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` and `$EntityName = 'App\\Entity\\' . ucwords($slug);`

Comment: and what is the outcome? what happens when you hardcode one entity like `$entityName = 'App\\Entity\\Members'` - note as well that I was using entityName instead of EntityName

Comment: you could even check out `$classes = $cmf->getAllMetadata();` to get metadata for all classes just for testing purposes

Comment: Ok, `$classes = $cmf->getAllMetadata();` gives me a result

Comment: then you should be able to identify which string to use for $entityName in getMetadataFor($entityName)

Comment: You mean this: `["rootEntityName"]=>
    string(18) "App\Entity\Members"`?

Comment: This is also giving me an output: `$classes = $cmf->getMetadataFor($EntityName);` if I make `var_dump($classes)`

Comment: Just the foreach is not giving me an output

Comment: `var_dump($classes)` gives me an output but if I add` foreach ($classes->fieldMappings as $fieldMapping) {
  echo $fieldMapping['fieldName'] . "\n";
}` Then there is no output

Comment: `["fieldMappings"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    array(9) {
      ["fieldName"]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["scale"]=>
      int(0)
      ["length"]=>
      NULL
      ["unique"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["nullable"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["precision"]=>
      int(0)
      ["id"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["columnName"]=>
      string(2) "id"
    }`

Comment: But in this array is also not the value of the id

Comment: what? look at your dump! it's there. of course "echo" won't "show" anything. use $fieldMapping['fieldName'] for whatever you would like to do with it. this has nothing to do with your OP but is simply PHP.

Comment: Now I am confused... I thought that foreach will output all the fields of the database table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179112/discussion-between-lba-and-jarla).

Comment: It will output the fields of the entity (your own dump result proves it!), but not the column of the database table. And in Symfony "echo" doesn't "output" to screen. Kind a difficult to explain these basics in such a context.